# Highcharts: save chart parameters when user changes them

Tags: highcharts

Basically I want to do simple thing - save to user cookie chart xAxis.min and xAsis.max when user uses the Navigator, so that next time I could show him chart on the same selected period.

Is there some kind of onChange event or I have to read chart's parameters in setInterval?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes)) or `xAxis.events.setExtremes` event. From your requirements I would assume that `afterSetExtremes` is sufficient.

If you want to only capture changes through the navigator you need to check 
`if(event.trigger == 'navigator')`, otherwise you can just look at general changes.

Here is [a JFiddle Highstock demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/) that shows the use of `setExtremes` event and what `event.trigger` values you can get.